# Refactoring a React function with repeated if else blocs

Tags: reactjs

I have some nasty code smell and want to refactor. My function has about 20 blocks of these if else statements and growing too. I had a go at refactoring but it didn't work because a) I am inexperienced in how to do it and b) the props need to be passed down again to the new function as a result of refactoring, and I don't know how to do this.

How would you refactor this function?

```
export default function myContent(props) {

  // Check for Kings
  if (props.tagText === `White's King is present`) {
    return <KingPresentWhite tagText={props.tagText} fen={props.fen} />;
  } else if (props.tagText === `Black's King is present`) {
    return <KingPresentBlack tagText={props.tagText} fen={props.fen} />;
  }

  // Check for unopposed Kings
  if (props.tagText.includes(`Unopposed`) & (props.tagColour === 'White')) {
    return <UnopposedKingWhite tagText={props.tagText} fen={props.fen} />;
  } else if (
    props.tagText.includes(`Unopposed`) &
    (props.tagColour === 'Black')
  ) {
    return <UnopposedKingBlack tagText={props.tagText} fen={props.fen} />;
  }

  // Lots more of these if else statement blocks, maybe about 20 of them

}
```

Answer (score 1):

My advice would be to not have so many different components. Why not have a Knight or even just Figure component which takes color, opposed status and type as parameters. That way the component does whatever it needs to do with that information internally (pethaps inside of a hook) and you dont need to do the if checks here. Presumably, a lot if the properties of these figures are shared.

Answer (score 0):

The only improvement I can see there is at the `return`. The `props` are the same for each component.

You can set a variable `type` that takes which component is returned. Then, at the end, you can return :

```
const element = React.createElement(type,
                [tagText={props.tagText}, fen={props.fen}])
return element;
```

However, from the way the second `if` statement is written, it may pose problems depending on the way the following checks are done.

What you could do is split that function in two. The first part doing the checks and returning a value. The second part, taking that value through a `switch` statement and returning the correct element.

The way information is passed, is also arguable. Giving information through sentences is not the best way. But, I don't know the inner working of your code and you may not be able to change that.
It's possible that multiples functions need to be refactored in order to have clean code.

Answer (score 0):

The flow of logic above doesn't make sense to me since an unopposed king implies that a king is in fact present, but if a king is present then the function returns before testing if unopposed. When logical conditions are mutually dependent like that, then the logic is usually cleaner if nested.

Another thing you can do is calculate conditions ahead of time using something like a "playerState" object as shown below. That helps by separating the way you define and test for conditions from the logical flow that depends on those conditions.

Lastly, whenever refactoring its a good idea to test early and test often. The code below shows example refactoring with mock data and log statements to confirm that it is working as expected. You can even run this code in a REPL session for real-time feedback. It's also a good idea to write automated tests that cover ever permutation of your logic.

```
let props = {
  tagText: "UnopposedKing is present",
  tagColor: "Black"
}

let playerState = {
  isBlack: props.tagColor.includes('Black'),
  hasKing: props.tagText.includes('King is present'),
  unopposed: props.tagText.includes('Unopposed')
}

if (playerState.isBlack) {
  if (playerState.hasKing) {
    if (playerState.unopposed) {
      console.log(playerState)
      //<UnopposedKingBlack...
    } else {
      console.log(playerState)
      //There is a king but the king is opposed
      //<OpposedKingBlack...
    }
  } else {
    console.log(playerState)
    //Something went wrong - did a player toss the board?
  }
} else {
  if (playerState.hasKing) {
    if (playerState.unopposed) {
      console.log(playerState)
      //<UnopposedKingWhite...
    } else {
      console.log(playerState)
      //There is a king but the king is opposed
      //<OpposedKingWhite...
    }
  } else {
    console.log(playerState)
    //Something went wrong - did a player toss the board?
  }
}
```

Finally, it makes sense to me to go a step further and combine the various components into a single component that handles these conditions as its own properties. As can be seen from the logic I posted, a lot of code is copied between black vs white, so making the component itself able to handle player color would be a good start. Also, it'd be good to move away from checking text and towards dedicated properties for the player state in general.